# Windows phone 7 create settings for application in settings section

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, mobile, application-settings

I'm a newbie in windows phone programming so plz excuse my ignorance. I have an application and I want to create a settings page for it in the phone settings, i.e settings -> myApp -> myAppSettingsPage. Is this possible or non-feasible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only OEMs (like Nokia and HTC) can add an entry to the Settings menu. So no, it isn't  possible.